# Build option is not working in Talend Job

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, talend, talend-mdm

I'm using Talend ESB 6.3 and creating jobs. I tried to use the build option in working job, but it is not working even it is not showing any error.

[image]

The above "FileCopyJob" right clicked & selected build option.

[image]

then clicked "Finish" button, building successfully & checked in file path.
There is no file in the saved path. did i missed anything in this process? How can i resolve the issue?

Here attached the JRE installed version in my machine.
[image]

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Extract an archive ? Generate job in order to import in the TAC?

Comment: Trying to generate the zip file of selected job.

Comment: two suggestions: a. make sure you are using JAVA 8, JDK (and your JAVA_HOME is updated)).  b. make sure both your JAVA and Talend installs match your computer architecture (32 or 64 bit).  For talend, it installs with both versions, just make sure your using the correct one.

Comment: I've checked the JDK, JRE and talend installed in 64 bit, but still i couldn't build the job.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
My solution : 
if you have your talend installed in a folder with space like this one "Talend Open Studio 6.3" : remove the space like that "TOS_6.3"
it worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to know when you run a job, Talend compile it.

So you have two possibilities :

- Build job : Create a zip of a job précompiled in order for example to import it in the Talend Administration Console (TAC) in order to run it. So when you build it you need a job without compilation error else the build won't work.
- Export Job : Create a Zip but not compiled. You can use this option in order to import the job in another Talend project or another computer if you have free version of Talend and you can't be more than one on a project.

If you choose "export" you need to select "Select archive File" and select all the thing you want to export.

Moreover they seem have the same probleem than you and some have solved : [Here](https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=44902)

Maybe your java install

Comment: in case of building job (c reating zip), I usually do it through main job (root). But I don't understand if I *really* have to check the Java sources when building the job if I want it to run it later, e.g. on Talend server.- I usually, submit .zip to GIT repo and we also have exported items as source (another .zip).

Answer (score 0):

This is the case if you have only installed and set up to use a JRE but not a JDK.

Go to

- Window
- Preferences
- Java
- Installed JREs

and make sure that no JRE is selected or even available in that list and only use to a JDK. I can see in your screenshot that a JDK is selected but make sure again it is a JDK.

[Source](https://help.talend.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=261820461&_ga=1.32202685.227922758.1471338566)

Answer (score 0):

This, and many other building problems in Talend O.S. 6.x (both ESB and DI products) are related with the <source> and <target> values, in the **pom.xml** of the .Java project, within the Talend workspace folder.

Try to set them to the JDK/JRE You configured in Talend properties. By example, if You configured Talend product to start and to build with JDK/JRE v 1.8, You should set the mentioned tags as follows:

```
<plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.5.1</version>
     <configuration>
       <source>1.8</source>
       <target>1.8</target>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Moreover, remember that when a Talend product builds (*generates Java sources and compiles 'em*) a Job, it's using Maven (*behind the scenes*) with the settings as defined in the following file:

`[Talend_install_dir]/configuration/maven_user_settings.xml`